# Get Stack Overflow stickers to an Asian country

Tags: discussion, swag

I'm in Sri Lanka, and I'd like to get some Stack Overflow stickers. I read the blog article *[How to Get Stack Overflow Stickers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/)* (2009), and it mentioned that I need to include $1 in the envelope. So, how do I get this done? I don't have any dollars so what do I need to include?

Comment: Maybe you could send 143.54 rupees and let the SO staff exchange them? (I actually don't know if that is possible, but you can ask them by email.)

Comment: Surely there are banks in Sri Lanka where you can exchange rupees for dollars.  You'll have to get out of the house, they don't come to you.  Include your mailing address.

Comment: Does Stack Overflow accept bitcoins? If not, is it because you cannot put them into an envelop?

Comment: @PreferenceBean Well, there are quite a few countries which use USD as an official currency. So it is _literally_ 9 countries or so :) Not saying that it is an excuse...

Comment: Many foreign exchange companies have minimum values that they will sell, so getting hold of a $1 bill could turn out expensive.

Comment: @zero323: don't ruin this with facts ;)

Comment: I live in Singapore and I got mine for free... OK, I *did* invest several years of my spare time.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions.! I'll try that Repay Coupon :)

Comment: Just... what is off topic about this?

Comment: It's [illegal to post bills or notes in Australia](http://auspost.com.au/parcels-mail/sending-valuable-items.html).

Comment: @Braiam: It got closed as "off-topic because it should be posted on meta", which is quite strange given that we are on meta.

Comment: I'd wager all you need to do is send them something neat from your country in barter.  Maybe a package of a local favorite candy?

Comment: @Will, maybe candy [like this](http://www.engrish.com/2014/04/define-candy/)?

Comment: That blog post is more than six years old. Are you sure it is not out of date?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, more or less. [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302694/4759033)

Comment: @MsYvette on the other hand, how would they ever possibly know? just send an envelope with a dollar wrapped in a piece of paper. i really don't think you're going to get in any trouble for sending a single dollar, even if it might be technically illegal.

Comment: I found these [guys](http://juststickers.in/) who print pretty good stickers in the Indian Subcontinent( I'm not associated with them), but can someone just print SO stickers, or is there a proper licensing mechanism in place?Living in India, can't do IRCs

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please note that sending actual cash in international mail may be prohibited by local laws.

---

The [original blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/how-to-get-stack-overflow-stickers/) actually mentions the correct way: you need to buy an [International Reply Coupon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_reply_coupon) and include that.

They are [sold by Sri Lanka post](http://www.slpost.gov.lk/international-mail/reply-coupons/):

> Reply coupons may be purchased at the price of Rs.250.00 each at any Post Office in Sri Lanka and each coupon is exchangeable in any foreign country of the Universal Postal Union for one or more postage stamps representing the postage payable on an unregistered letter of the first step abroad by surface mail.

For other countries, refer to the [UPU list](http://www.upu.int/en/activities/international-reply-coupons/countries-selling-ircs.html).

---

If your country doesn't sell IRCs, you can order them abroad.

- Swiss Post [sells them with worldwide delivery](https://www.postshop.ch/en/Products/Stamps/Pre-franked-products/International-reply-coupon-1943400).
- (feel free to edit in more sources)

---

P.S. Don't forget to include a self-addressed envelope for them to use.

Comment: And if all else fails, the IRCs can be used to run a Ponzi scheme

Comment: @CodyGray You mean [_the_ Ponzi scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_reply_coupon#The_Ponzi_scheme).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that Repay Coupon :)

Comment: What about countries that don't have it?OP from India

Comment: @SatejS No ready solution in that case. You could try getting touch with them to ask.

Comment: International Reply Coupons haven't been available in UK [since 2011](http://www.royalmail.com/reply-sender) :(

Comment: @MacroMan One could, in theory, order them abroad.. Which a very roundabout way, but still. For example, https://www.postshop.ch/en/Products/Stamps/Pre-franked-products/International-reply-coupon-1943400 is available for worldwide mailing.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure what blog post you read, but the one I immediately thought of was the (now hilariously obsolete) [A New Name for Stack Overflow (with surprise ending)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/a-new-name-for-stack-overflow-with-surprise-ending/) which concludes with

> If you live outside the United States, include about a dollar worth of whatever kind of weird thing it is that you use over there for money (no goats or Yap coins, please).

So you don't really need a dollar, just about a dollar worth of stuff. I probably shouldn't speak for the office staff, but I'm gonna go ahead and do it anyways: I have to think it's not worth actually exchanging such a small amount of money, and they just keep the money around as a souvenir. In the past, we've even recommended just sending little trinkets representative of your home country as an alternative to cash or cash equivalents.

To reiterate what commenters and the first answer already pointed out, mailing cash is even illegal in some countries, and the most important thing we need from you is the pre-addressed reply envelope.

Comment: Did it become *hilariously obsolete* because of [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow)?

Comment: You have understood my point exactly, sir.